# Updating state using api in useLayoutEffect does not work before painting component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  getUser()
    .then(res => setGlobalUser(res.data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

The `getUser` method exists for API calls. I am trying to display the user profile when the user refreshes the website.
That's why I used `useLayoutEffect` because I wanted to update the `globalUser` state before painting and then show it when the web page is painted.

But the `globalUser` state value is `null` when I refresh the page, then quickly re-render then show the user profile information on the web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`useLayoutEffect`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useLayoutEffect#measuring-layout-before-the-browser-repaints-the-screen) is a hook mainly to read the layout of a component before painting. It's not designed for data fetching. What you want can be achieved with `useEffect` and a conditional rendering. As an example like so:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  getUser()
    .then(res => setGlobalUser(res.data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
})

if(!globalUser) {
  // you can return a loader here if you want
  return null;
}
```